# What are the consequences of turning off only_full_group_by sql_mode?

Tags: mysql

I am collecting SSH brute force data, and store it in a table called "attempts".  I want to GROUP BY each IP address with the associated location data and country name, but I cannot do this with only_full_group_by enabled.  I disabled it and my query works fine, but I have two questions:

1. What are the consequences of disabling only_full_group_by?  I assume it is a default for a reason, why is that?  I can see issues if the same IP address had different location data for each record, but is that the only scenario where things go wrong?
2. If I wanted to accomplish the query without disabling only_full_group_by, what would that query look like?

My code:

```
SELECT latitude,longitude,country_name,foreign_ip,g.count as counter
FROM attempts
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(foreign_ip) as count,foreign_ip as fi
    FROM attempts
    GROUP BY foreign_ip
) as g on attempts.foreign_ip = g.fi
GROUP BY foreign_ip;
```

Comment: Nothing good can come from it.

Comment: @Strawberry: That's not very enlightening.

Comment: @lako65: What would be the purpose of turning it off?

Comment: I get this error with it on: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ssh_brute_force.attempts.latitude' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Ah, well I'd fix your query first, before trying to monkey with MySQL's default settings.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume it is a default for a reason, why is that?

The `only_full_group_by` prevents using `GROUP BY` in ways that are incorrect. Having it on by default is a good thing.

You can write the query without the subquery:

```
SELECT latitude,longitude,country_name, foreign_ip,count(*) as counter
FROM attempts
GROUP BY latitude,longitude,country_name, foreign_ip
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know. For some reason I thought you couldn't specify multiple columns with GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has historically been very tolerant with user errors. That often leads to additional work (e.g. first you store dates and then you need to filter invalid ones one every select) and data loss (your column is too short for the data and you end up with truncated data). They're trying to fix that but they cannot break a million apps that rely on tolerant behaviour so the solution has been to add optional SQL models.

If all columns within groups have the same values, you're right, nothing will break. The problem is when that isn't true. MySQL will not warn you and, instead, will just retrieve an arbitrary (not even random) row per group.

Your current query can be easily fixed to work in either mode:

```
SELECT latitude,longitude,country_name,foreign_ip,g.count as counter
FROM attempts
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(foreign_ip) as count,foreign_ip as fi
    FROM attempts
    GROUP BY foreign_ip
) as g on attempts.foreign_ip = g.fi
GROUP BY latitude,longitude,country_name,foreign_ip,g.count
```

Comment: If you want to get unique rows, use DISTINCT. The GROUP BY should be used when you mix plain columns with aggregate functions.

Comment: It's not uncommon that they generate the same execution plan, though.

Comment: if you check with the profiler, they usually execute the queries bit differently. The result will be the same though.